# PHP MYSQL COMBINE STRING

Tags: php, mysql

```
Table `names`
ID | name 
---------
1  | Alex
2  | John
3  | Alex
4  | Alex
5  | Alice
6  | Monica

SELECT `name` FROM `names` GROUP BY `name`
Alex
John
Alice
MOnica
```

> so, I need to make like this

```
SELECT `name`, COMBINE_STRING(`ID`, SEPARATOR `,`) AS `IDS` FROM `names` GROUP BY `name`

and the result should be like this :
```

> and the result will be like this :

```
NAME | IDS
------------
Alex   1,3,4
John   2
Alice  5
MOnica 6
```

> but as you see that mysql function COMBINE_STRING doesn't exist, so
>   any ideas how to do this?

Comment: Use `CONCAT` for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply you can use [`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-group_concat/) function of `MySql` which'll work for you as like of your `COMBINE_STRING`

```
SELECT `name`, GROUP_CONCAT(`ID`) AS `IDS` FROM `names` GROUP BY `name`
```

Comment: Thanks, but actually I already figured it out by my self, but anyway ur example is that what I need, thx a lot!

Comment: @AleksandrSasha You're welcome. Glad to help. (_FYI: You can accept or upvote an answer which really helps you_)

Answer (score 1):

Change `COMBINE_STRING` to `group_concat` so it becomes

```
SELECT `name`, group_concat(`ID`) AS `IDS` FROM `names` GROUP BY `name`
```

`,` is default separator for the `group_concat` when explicitly not provided.